# Can't update resource from ActiveAdmin interface -- ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When I try to update the content of a resource in the Active Admin interface, I receive this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Admin::ThingsController#update
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

[image: Error Message]

Here are the contents of the update action in the ThingsController

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @thing.update(thing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Thing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @thing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What do I have to add to this block to get this to work? I also noticed that I **cannot create** a new resource in the Active Admin interface either. However, I can delete them.

Comment: Please paste your `thing_params` method source.

Comment: Or the whole `Admin::ThingsController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding this to admin/thing.rb

```
controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit thing: [ :title, :description, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, ":image_updated_at(1i)", ":image_updated_at(2i)", ":image_updated_at(3i)", ":image_updated_at(4i)", ":image_updated_at(5i)"  ]
    end
```